# CollectionUtils - Transformer - Any peformance issues?

Tags: java, performance, collections, apache-commons

I am planning to use

```
CollectionUtils.collect(myCollection, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getID"));
```

and want to know if there are any known performance issues with Transformer as it uses reflection. I am on JDK1.6 so no luxury of lambdas.

**EDIT**:I am trying to Iterate through an object collection(e.g. Houses) and extract another collection of a original object's field(e.g. House_Id) and wanted to avoid FOR loop to make code more readable but not necessarily take a perf hit.

Comment: Java 8 Lamdas are only syntactic sugar. They don't allow you to do anything you couldn't have previously done with anonymous classes. Thus they don't themselves add any performance gain. They do however make code more readable and concise.

Comment: There is considerable debate about the concept of lambdas being mere syntactic sugar. From my pov it is syntactic sugar in the sense that it makes code more readable and understandable than anonymous classes. Under the hood however they are implemented differently. Brian Goetz explains here: http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/7/7b/Goetz-jvmls-lambda.pdf. In terms of performance I haven't seen a demonstrated runtime gain; with everything performance you should always test and not assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is known to cause performance hits because of the dynamic resolution that is inherent in the mechanism. The question of course is subjective as the particular transformer you use might be more efficient than another.

You could also implement your own transformer.

At the end of the day you should test the performance of the operation and determine if it falls within an acceptable range.

You never specified what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps there is a better alternative.